# The constructor BasicNameValuePair(String, Spanned) in undefined while using Html.fromHtml(message)

Tags: android, html, email

I want to insert html code inside body of an email ... in my code i am sending email at background means onClick event of a button as whenever i use Html.formHtml inside BasicNameValuePair it shows error on this line .. please help 
Thank you

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg)
{
    String site = "http://2233.comoj.com/mailer.php";
    String namer1 = "password";
    String to = "abc@gmail.com";
    String from = "xyz@gmail.com";
    String subject1 = "checking mail";
    String message = "<html><head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></head></html>";
    String content = "";

    try
    {
        /* Sends data through a HTTP POST request */
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(site);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", namer1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", to));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", from));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", subject1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", Html.fromHtml(message))); //error in this line 
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
        /* Reads the server response */
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int chr;
        while ((chr = in.read()) != -1)
        {
            sb.append((char) chr);
        }
        content = sb.toString();
        in.close();
        /* If there is a response, display it */
        if (!content.equals(""))
        {
            Log.i("HTTP Response", content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Invite2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: On which line, post logcat please

Comment: in this line params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", Html.fromHtml(message))); when i save my code error shows that "The constructor BasicNameValuePair(String, Spanned) in undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `toString()` on the `Html.fromHtml` method (as it returns a `Spanned`) to be able to put it as a value inside a `NameValuePair`.

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", Html.fromHtml(message).toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) Reference
the method `fromHtml` is return a `Spanned`

I think you just use just send a `String`

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
```